# Merge for mergesort in scala

Tags: scala, merge, functional-programming, mergesort

I'm migrating from Java to Scala and I am trying to come up with the procedure merge for mergesort algorithm. My solution:

```
  def merge(src: Array[Int], dst: Array[Int], from: Int,
            mid: Int, until: Int): Unit = {

        /*
         * Iteration of merge:
         * i - index of src[from, mid)
         * j - index of src[mid, until)
         * k - index of dst[from, until)
         */
        @tailrec
        def loop(i: Int, j: Int, k: Int): Unit = {
            if (k >= until) {
                // end of recursive calls
            } else if (i >= mid) {
                dst(k) = src(j)
                loop(i, j + 1, k + 1)
            } else if (j >= until) {
                dst(k) = src(j)
                loop(i + 1, j, k + 1)
            } else if (src(i) <= src(j)) {
                dst(k) = src(i);
                loop(i + 1, j, k + 1)
            } else {
                dst(k) = src(j)
                loop(i, j + 1, k + 1)
            }
        }
        loop(from, mid, from)
  }
```

seems to work, but it seems to me that it is written in quite "imperative" style
(despite i have used recursion and no mutable variables except for the arrays, for which the side effect is intended). I want something like this:

```
/*
 * this code is not working and at all does the wrong things
 */
for (i <- (from until mid); j <- (mid until until); 
    k <- (from until until) if <???>) yield dst(k) = src(<???>)
```

But i cant come up with the proper solution of such kind. Can you please help me?

Comment: Maybe your problem belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ..

Comment: @meucaa Potentially, but not as currently written. Code Review question are of the form "Here is code that does X, how could it have been done better" rather than "Here is code that does X, how can I make it do Y instead". If the OP dropped the second part of their question, it would be a good fit for CR.

Comment: @Zak acturally I'm asking how this can be done better, i don't want the code to do anything instead of merge.

Comment: @meucaa I had a look at coderewiew, but most of the searches on merge considered concatenation operation ++ or some other not so related topics

Comment: @KonstantinK, the idea of codereview is not to find similar code to yours, but to post your code and ask for suggestions. I think CodeReview is an appropriate place for this

Comment: @KonstantinK You should definitely post on Code Review :)

Comment: @KonstantinK I'm not disagreeing, just saying that the second part of your question "I want something like this:" would not be a good fit for Code Review and should be removed if you want to post it over there.

Comment: @ Zak Sorry... I misunderstood you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
  val left = src.slice(from, mid).buffered
  val right = src.slice(mid, until).buffered

  (from until until) foreach { k => 
    dst(k) = if(!left.hasNext) right.next 
      else if(!right.hasNext || left.head < right.head) left.next
      else right.next
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, thats definitely more elegant solution than mine. Probably I have to read up on iterators in scala more.